# What's the best way to create a dummy $resource for development purposes in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

I'm developing an Angular app (actually, an Ionic app) that relies on a REST API. To communicate with the API, I will inject `$resource`s into my controllers.

I want to focus on the app now, and worry about the backend later—so I'd like to create dummy versions of my various `$resource`s. For example, my dummy `Products` $resource will contain a few sample product records (hardcoded as JSON), and will support/mimic the same CRUD operations that the *real* `$resource` will eventually support.

In other words, it will be [similar to this](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-tabs/blob/master/js/services.js)—but will mimic the same API as `$resource` (promises, error handling, etc.).

Obviously, I could roll my own solution to this—but surely this is already a solved problem. What's the standard approach?

(I've done a fair bit of Googling around this, but everything I find talks about unit testing and test frameworks—which I know little about. Anyway, that seems like a slightly different problem than the one I'm trying to solve. I've also seen a lot about [`$httpBackend`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend)—but (1) that mocks the lower-level `$http` service, not `$resource`, which is what I need, and (2) it seems to be meant for use in the context of unit tests, which is not what I'm trying to do.)

Comment: There are several dynamic json generator sites that you can use.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not asking how to generate the dummy data. I'm asking about the cleanest way to mock up a $resource, so I don't have to go to the trouble of building a real backend API before I can start writing my client code.

Comment: but the sites I'm talking about will serve the data and act as your back end

Comment: Ah, I see. Have an example? If it lets me describe the API in sufficient detail, it might be an option...

Comment: not hard to get a good list of them in a google search https://www.google.com/search?q=json+generator+online&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: I wasn't sure what to search for. All of those results seem to be sites that generate JSON dummy data. I don't see anything that lets you set up an actual, functioning REST API, as you describe.

I'd prefer an offline solution anyway; no sense in coupling my app to some random website. Thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: `$resource` is just a wrapper around `$http`, so the official method to solve this is `$httpBackend`.  There *might* be 3rd party tools that are more comprehensive, but that would make the question a request for off site resources (off topic).  Even if the question was about how to "roll your own", it's not focused enough for a single comprehensive answer that isn't a library written in the answer.

Comment: So how would I use `$httpBackend` without a testing framework? All of the examples I've found use `$httpBackend` in the context of unit tests, which is not what I'm trying to do (and not something I know *how* to do, although I intend to learn eventually).

Answer (score 0):

I finally found [an example of using `$httpBackend` without a unit test](http://jsfiddle.net/joshdmiller/egmpe/).

Essentially, you can inject `$httpBackend` into the `run()` method of your module, like this:

```
app.run(function($httpBackend) {

  var phones = [{name: 'phone1'}, {name: 'phone2'}]; 

  $httpBackend.whenPOST('/phones').respond(function(method, url, data, headers){
    console.log('Received these data:', method, url, data, headers);
    phones.push(angular.fromJson(data));
    return [200, {}, {}];
  });

  $httpBackend.whenGET('/phones').respond(function(method,url,data) {
    console.log("Getting phones");
    return [200, phones, {}];
  });
});
```